# compile c++ code into pyd with cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

Cython compiles a python-like code to a C++ Code then it uses gcc/g++ to compile it into a library like pyd.

Lets say i would write my code in pure C++ then compile it into pyd to use it in Python for example lets say i have the following C++ module

```
int sum(int a, int b){
    return a + b
}
```

Is it possible to compile that code into pyd without using something like PyObject, Ctype ... etc? or does the code must be in the first place written with Cython Syntax to be compatible with Python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert on this, but as noone answered yet, here is my opinion:

You should use cython if you want to avoid using PyObject structures and "Python.h" in C.

The trouble is that **.pyd is a specially prepaired DLL that exposes **import**() friendly interface, that, I think, includes returning PyObjects.

But using ctypes on normal DLL or shared object lib isn't hard:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> mysum = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("mysum.so") # Or DLL
>>> print mysum.sum(2, 3)
5
```

You'll just have to export the sum function to be available from dynamic library and compile your code as such.

Comment: do you think ctypes is able to work with complex C++ modules such OpenGL applications ?

Comment: I believe (although I could be wrong) that the Python OpenGL wrapper uses ctypes.

Comment: I think it does. I'm not OpenGL fan, so I am not sure.  Yes, you can wrap anything using ctypes. You just have to know what input the shared library function requires and what type should be the output. For complex data types with structures, you will have to declare them yourself, so the DLL have to be well documented, or you have to be excellent hacker and dig through DLL  manually, or be the author of it. :D

Comment: It doesn't matter in which language the DLL is written. You just have to know its interface and ctypes will do it. One method for making C Python extensions is to use SWIG. So sniff around for it as well.